# Wordpress is showing a blank page after migration

Tags: php, wordpress

The error occurs only with this theme.

I have an error when i go to single post, it´s showing a blank page, only with this theme, this should be working after migration.

With debug mode i find an error in single.php, bad final :D

Here is the code of the single.php page:

http://pastebin.com/nntXdfVk

Comment: what theme are you using? what wordpress and php version? what steps you followed in your migration process?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have BOM at the begining of the file (before the first `<?php`
It looks like there is a fatal error/exception being thrown for some reason, and you do not see the error messages. I suggest you go line by line debugging.